# Adding music to my sound board project

Tags: java, audio

So I'm creating a soundboard for my CS project using java. The soundboard consists of an 8 piece drum set that is supposed to play its set sound when clicked. I've set the area to be clicked but don't know how to implement sound that'll start when the set area is clicked.

```
// FinalProjectst.java
// AP Computer ScienceStudent Version


import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;


public class FinalProjectst extends Applet
{
    Image picture;
    Ellipse2D base, bT, snare, lT, rT, hh, lC, rC;
    int numColor;

    public void init()
    {
        picture = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"drumSet.jpg");

        base  = new Ellipse2D.Double (355, 415, 305, 240); //Bass
        bT    = new Ellipse2D.Double (715, 360, 325, 245); //Bottom Tom
        snare = new Ellipse2D.Double ( 35, 410, 290, 200); //Snare
        lT    = new Ellipse2D.Double (283, 130, 185, 165); //Left Tom
        rT    = new Ellipse2D.Double (543, 120, 200, 175); //Right Tom
        hh    = new Ellipse2D.Double (  0, 225, 250, 150); //High Hat
        lC    = new Ellipse2D.Double ( 10,   0, 305, 195); //Left Cymbal
        rC    = new Ellipse2D.Double (765,   0, 505, 275); //Right Cymbal
    }


    public boolean contains(Event e, int x, int y)
    {
        if(base.contains(x,y))
            numColor = 1;
        else if(bT.contains(x,y))
            numColor = 2;
        else if(snare.contains(x,y))
            numColor = 3;
        else if(lT.contains(x,y))
            numColor = 4;
        else if(rT.contains(x,y))
            numColor = 5;
        else if(hh.contains(x,y))
            numColor = 6;
        else if(lC.contains(x,y))
            numColor = 7;
        else if(rC.contains(x,y))
            numColor = 8;
        else
            numColor = 9;
        repaint();
        return true;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

        g.drawImage(picture, 0, 0, this);


    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to play a sound but for example you could do something like this:

```
public static void playSound(File soundfile)  throws LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException{
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = null;
        audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundfile);              
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();              
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();
}
```

This code will play wav files without a problem and I think that it will also play other types of sound files, but I am not sure what sound types it will play and what sound types it will not.

I hope this help :)

EDIT:

As you can see there are a lot of exceptions that can be thrown from this code, so you probably want to handle them in an appropriate way.

Comment: Yeah that's true but I have no idea how the OP is going about handeling exceptions, so it's up to him to decide how to handle the exceptions and NPE's. If this were in one of my programms I would have already made some class for handeling and reporting/logging errors. Good point though.

Comment: Good point I'll do that right now. It looks much cleaner now thank you for the suggestion.